# PyBindGen with callback

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, callback, pybindgen

I am trying to use PyBindGen to create a python extension module for my C library which has a callback. Even though [PyBindGen frontpage](https://pypi.org/project/PyBindGen/) says that callbacks are a missing feature, the current source code and [this discussion](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cplusplus-sig/2010-May/015512.html) and [archive](http://%20http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gjc/pybindgen/trunk/revision/766) have examples of how to setup PyBindGen to pass a callback function from python into the C library.

The problem is that the example defines the callback method to have the `PyObject*` as a `void *` argument to carry the callback function pointer information. Since my API does not have such a context pointer, I am trying to keep the reference to the callback inside the C bindings code [similar to standard python example](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#writing-extensions-in-c). The problem is that I cannot figure out how to get PyBindGen to set the global PyObject * my_callback. How can I do that? Here's my code

My library header file

```
typedef void (*CallbackType) (int value);
void register_cb(CallbackType cb);
void set_num(int n);
```

My library source file

```
#include "c.h"

static CallbackType cb_;
void register_cb(CallbackType cb)
{
    cb_ = cb;
}
void set_num(int n)
{
    cb_(n);
}
```

My PyBindGen modulegen.py **with a commented section of what needs to be added** to auto-generated code for this to work

```
import sys
import pybindgen
from pybindgen import ReturnValue, Parameter, Module, Function, FileCodeSink
from pybindgen import CppMethod, CppConstructor, CppClass, Enum
from pybindgen.typehandlers.base import ForwardWrapperBase

class CallbackTypeParam(Parameter):

    DIRECTIONS = [Parameter.DIRECTION_IN]
    CTYPES = ['CallbackType']

    def convert_python_to_c(self, wrapper):
        assert isinstance(wrapper, ForwardWrapperBase)

        py_cb = wrapper.declarations.declare_variable("PyObject*", self.name)
        wrapper.parse_params.add_parameter('O', ['&'+py_cb], self.name)
        wrapper.before_call.write_error_check("!PyCallable_Check(%s)" % py_cb, """PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "CallbackType parameter must be callable");""")

        #####
        # NEED TO INSERT THE FOLLOWING TWO LINES INTO AUTOGENERATED OUTPUT HERE
        #    Py_XDECREF(my_callback); // NEEDS TO BE AUTO-GENERATED !!!
        #    my_callback = cb;        // NEEDS TO BE AUTO-GENERATED !!!
        #####

        wrapper.call_params.append("_wrap_callback")
        wrapper.before_call.write_code("Py_INCREF(%s);" % py_cb)
        wrapper.before_call.add_cleanup_code("Py_DECREF(%s);" % py_cb)

    def convert_c_to_python(self, wrapper):
        raise NotImplementedError


def my_module_gen(out_file):

    mod = Module('c')
    mod.add_include('"c.h"')

    mod.header.writeln("""
void _wrap_callback(int value);
static PyObject *my_callback = NULL;
""")

    mod.body.writeln("""
void _wrap_callback(int value)
{
int arg;
PyObject *arglist;

arg = value;
printf("@@@@ Inside the binding: %d %p\\n", value, my_callback); fflush(NULL);

arglist = Py_BuildValue("(i)", arg);
PyObject_CallObject(my_callback, arglist);
Py_DECREF(arglist);
}
""")


    mod.add_function("register_cb", None, [Parameter.new("CallbackType", "cb")])
    mod.add_function("set_num", None, [Parameter.new("int", "n")])

    mod.generate(FileCodeSink(out_file))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_module_gen(sys.stdout)
```

My setup.py file for building the extension module

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from modulegen import my_module_gen as generate

try:
    os.mkdir("build")
except OSError:
    pass
os.environ["CC"] = "g++"
module_fname = os.path.join("build", "autogen-binding.c")
with open(module_fname, "wt") as file_:
    print("Generating file {}".format(module_fname))
    generate(file_)

mymodule = Extension('c',
                    sources = [module_fname, 'c.cc'],
                    include_dirs=['.'])

setup(name='PyBindGen-example',
    version="0.0",
    description='PyBindGen example',
    author='xxx',
    author_email='yyy@zz',
    ext_modules=[mymodule],
    )
```

My python script using the extension module

```
import c

def my_callback(value):
    print("In Callback: " + str(value))

c.register_cb(my_callback)
c.set_num(10);
c.set_num(20);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In hind sight, it is obvious. I simply had to put the desired lines into a call to `wrapper.before_call.write_code()` at the place where I expected the actual C lines to appear.